# Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 - Dropbox SDK in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, dropbox-api

I am new in iOS development. In my application i am  trying to include Dropbox API. After including this API i am getting below error.

Do needful in this.

```
-[MPOAuthCredentialConcreteStore(KeychainAdditions) addToKeychainUsingName:andValue] in DropboxSDK
  "_kSecAttrSecurityDomain", referenced from:
      -[MPOAuthCredentialConcreteStore(KeychainAdditions) addToKeychainUsingName:andValue] in DropboxSDK
      -[MPOAuthCredentialConcreteStore(KeychainAdditions) findValueFromKeychainUsingName:returningItem in DropboxSDK
      -[MPOAuthCredentialConcreteStore(KeychainAdditions) removeValueFromKeychainUsingName] in DropboxSDK
  "_kSecAttrServer", referenced from:
      -[MPOAuthCredentialConcreteStore(KeychainAdditions) addToKeychainUsingName:andValue] in DropboxSDK
      -[MPOAuthCredentialConcreteStore(KeychainAdditions) findValueFromKeychainUsingName:returningItem] in DropboxSDK
      -[MPOAuthCredentialConcreteStore(KeychainAdditions) removeValueFromKeychainUsingName] in DropboxSDK
  "_kSecAttrService", referenced from:
      +[DBKeychain initialize] in DropboxSDK
  "_kSecAttrType", referenced from:
      -[MPOAuthCredentialConcreteStore(KeychainAdditions) addToKeychainUsingName:andValue] in DropboxSDK
  "_kSecClass", referenced from:
      -[MPOAuthCredentialConcreteStore(KeychainAdditions) addToKeychainUsingName:andValue in DropboxSDK
      -[MPOAuthCredentialConcreteStore(KeychainAdditions) findValueFromKeychainUsingName:returningItem] in DropboxSDK
      -[MPOAuthCredentialConcreteStore(KeychainAdditions) removeValueFromKeychainUsingName in DropboxSDK
      +[DBKeychain initialize] in DropboxSDK
      +[DBKeychain setCredentials in DropboxSDK
  "_kSecClassGenericPassword", referenced from:
      +[DBKeychain initialize] in DropboxSDK
  "_kSecClassInternetPassword", referenced from:
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you didnt forget to add `Security.framewok`

Comment: Thank you for answer Anil. But already i added this framework.

Comment: All the symbols are from the security framework only. Can re check it again framework is properly linked

Comment: I am add the droupbox API and i am build than give above error. and i am remove droupbox API than all error are remove. I don't know what is Actual problem.  Thanks..